# How to define discrete color map automatically in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to define automatically `total` colors equally distributed in the color map below? I mean, for `i` from `1` to `total` I'd like to get a color `c-i`, where `c-0` is the left most blue color and `c-total` is the right most red color.

I'd like to use this procedure to fill the circles in the MWE below.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\total{10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,\total}{
\draw[fill] (\x,0) circle (.5cm);
%\draw[fill=<color should be here, depending on \x>] (\x,0) circle (.5cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `HSB` model?

Comment: @Symbol1, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 6):

`pgfplots` has this in `color of colormap`, see p. 211 of the manual

[image]

There are tons of colormaps, and each of them can be accessed with an index that runs from 0 to 1000.

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\def\total{10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,\total}{
\fill[/pgfplots/color of colormap=\x*100 of hot] (\x,0) circle[radius=.5cm];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that many nice options are collected in section **5.2 ColorBrewer** of pgfplots manual v1.16.

The colormap that seems to come close to your screen shot is called jet. Here are two series of circles, the upper ones are discrete steps, whereas the lower ones have a continuous color transition.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/colormap={jet}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,128) rgb255(1cm)=(0,0,255)
rgb255(3cm)=(0,255,255) rgb255(5cm)=(255,255,0) rgb255(7cm)=(255,0,0)
rgb255(8cm)=(128,0,0)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=1.55,xshift=0.5cm]
\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[,
    colormap={myjet}{
        samples of colormap=(8 of jet)
    },
    colorbar horizontal,
    colormap access=map,
    xticklabel style={opacity=0,overlay}
]
\end{scope}
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
\fill[/pgfplots/color of colormap=\x*100 of jet] (\x,-2.25) circle[radius=.5cm];
}

\path[clip] foreach \X in {1,...,10}{ (\X,-5)circle[radius=.5cm]};
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3.6cm,xscale=1.8,yscale=2.5]
\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[,
    colormap={myjet}{
        samples of colormap=(8 of jet)
    },
    colorbar horizontal,
    colormap access=map,
    xticklabel style={opacity=0,overlay}
]
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The lower ones are somewhat harder to obtain with Ti*k*Z "only" (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: Perfect. I didn't know about `/pgfplots/color of colormap=`.

Comment: @Sigur I thought the answer achieves something along those lines already. Anyway, I added some color map which seems to be closer to your screen shot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll see other color maps also. Maybe some with very distinct colors. But your solution teaches me a lot.

Comment: Maybe you want `\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading`.

Comment: @Symbol1 Yes, that's also a possibility but to the best of my knowledge it does not come with a built-in `color of colormap` key. That is, even if you have declared the shading, you do not know what the color is at, say 12% of the full length. Of course, one can figure this out, but this is what `pgfplots` spares us from doing.

Comment: I see what you mean. You want the strip plus the ability to put a color somewhere else.

Comment: @Symbol1 This was how I read the question (but I am not sure).

Comment: OK let me clarify: I was commenting on `The lower ones are somewhat harder to obtain with TikZ` while I thought it is clipping plus `\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading`.

Comment: @Symbol1 Oh, good point! I agree.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the wavelength color model

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \def\total{10}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,\total}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\wavelen{400+(700-400)*\x/\total}
        \definecolor{ad hoc color}{wave}{\wavelen}
        \fill[ad hoc color](\x,0)circle(.5cm);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Strange, I'm not using the class like you (`\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}`). I'm loading `tikz` after. When I tried to fill using the color, I get `Package pgf Error: Unsupported color model `hsb'.`

Comment: That is indeed weird. Maybe double check with the xcolor manual. It could be possible that TikZ/xcolor loads a different driver that does not support wave.

Comment: Hum, something strange in my complex drawing code. Your MWE works. Let me check.

Comment: Curious. `\draw[fill={ad hoc color}]` does not work. Neither `\draw[fill=ad hoc color]`. But `\fill[ad hoc color,draw=black](\x,0)circle(.5cm);` does.

Comment: That, I think, is interesting enough to become a new question. Bother/Consider asking?